# onPostExecute not being called by ASyncTask execute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I can't explain why onPostExecute is not being called in my code. I have successfully used almost this exact code with a different app before. It prints 'onPreExecute' and the successful result of the JSON fetch from doInBackground just before `return result;` but then onPostExecute doesn't print anything - with the super call or not - and moreover doesn't return my string to the UI thread. Any ideas?

```
public class PrivateLoadFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = null;
    String error_text="";
    JSONObject j = null;
    String url;
    SQLiteOpenHelper helper;
    CustomActivity activity;
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private int count;
    String employee;
    String text;

    public PrivateLoadFromServer(CustomActivity activity,String employee,String url){
        this.url=url;
        this.employee=employee;
        this.activity=activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        system.out.println("onPreExecute");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        System.out.println("onPostExecute");

        activity.setJSONResult(result);
        /*
        if(result!=null){
            System.out.println("Task reported successful");
            taskHandler.taskSuccessful(this.result);
            activity.setJSONResult(this.result);
        } else {
            taskHandler.taskFailed();
        }
        */
        //return;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        System.out.println("Running aSyncTask");

            // Successful code to get JSON result string from server omitted.

        System.out.println("Raw at doInBackground: " + result);
    return result;
```

EDIT: Should've posted this originally, I call it as an inner class in CustomActivity like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    helper=new DBHelper(this);
    loadBasicData();

}

 private void loadBasicData() {

    // If you can encode all of these into one JSON Object, cool.

    String url="*****" //Omitted URL.
    String employee=null;

    PrivateLoadFromServer syncTask = new PrivateLoadFromServer(this,employee,url);

    syncTask.execute();

    try {
        syncTask.get(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("JSONResult at Activity:"+jsonResult); // jsonResult is null

    }
}

    public void setJSONResult(String result){
    System.out.println("setJSONResult"+result);
    this.jsonResult=result; // jsonResult is a field in the Activity.
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense using the `AsyncTask` class in order to perform async operations and still block the main thread calling the `.get()` method. Also, the problem you are experiencing always occurs or just if you rotate the screen while loading?

Comment: Always occurs, nothing to do with rotation. And I have to block the main thread so that I have the JSON result before I call the method loading it to my local database, or it fails with a null pointer.

Comment: Can't you perform your database loading in the `AsyncTask` after the network request is done? I'm not sure this is the problem (it could be), but for sure your current approach will cause you other problems (ANR, for example).

Comment: Oh I'll give that a shot. You mean to use the database load method in doInBackground rather than passing to the UI thread with onPostExecute?

Comment: I think the problems are being caused by the way you are sleeping the main thread. You need to put your output statement `System.out.println("JSONResult at Activity:"+jsonResult);` inside onPostExecute() and don't sleep the main thread while your Async is running. on a side note you should be using androids Log class instead of `System.out`

Comment: And yes I know ANR is an issue with using `.get()` but for some reason using a ProgressBar in this app causes errors, unlike when I used this code in a previous app.

Comment: +1 for @FoamyGuy. @Callum Jenkins you could also move your database operations directly inside `doInBackground`.

Comment: The accepted answer lets me bring the result into the UI thread easily with my current code, but I will shift my database operations into doInBackground later. Thanks for the suggestions everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are calling get, the JSON result is also returned from this method (see the source code of [AsyncTask.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java). So you can call your method directly on the output.

```
try {
    setJSONResult(syncTask.get(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I'm still not calling onPostExecute but that does let me bring the result straight into the UI thread, so that works, thanks very much :) I will probably end up bringing the database operations into the ASync thread as the main post commenters suggest in the end in order to remove the `.get()\ though.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your are explicitly cancelling AsyncTask somewhere in the code before it could postExecute.

Comment: No call to cancel anywhere.

Comment: Why are you blocking your main thread ? That does not make any sense.

Comment: See my comment to the main post. The same is said e.g. here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/YcuihmCP2Fc

Answer (score 0):

onPostExecute() is called on the main UI thread. If its not getting called, it means your UI thread is blocked doing something else.